# How to allow both integers and strings in input?

Tags: python, string, input, integer

I just started learning Python about a week ago, and for one of my first projects I built a really simple random number guessing game as part of the course I'm in. However, I tried to add an extension to my code that would print something different if the word "no" was entered as an input, even though the input only accepts integers in my code. In a previous question, I learned that try/except could be used to print something if an error occurred, (such as by entering "no" instead of an integer) per the following template:

[image]

In turn, my code looks like this:

[image]

And the output I get when I enter no looks like this:

Enter a number between 1 and 21: no

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/camer/Desktop/Python/randomintproject.py", line 3, in <module>
    guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 21: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'no'
```

If the template code works, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post code as text, not as image.

Comment: You do the conversion outside try/except, so it doesn't get caught.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you. Also as other users have pointed out, do not take pictures of your code: Paste it in the question as text instead.

Comment: Please paste your code in an [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert all inputs to `int` by wrapping `input()` with `int()`

Try this:

```
inp = input('enter a number...')

if inp.isnumeric():  # checks if input is numeric, i.e. 2, 39, 4592 etc
    inp = int(inp) 
else:  # Was not numeric, i.e. was a letter, word or some character
    print "OK forget it"
```

Another way would be:

```
inp = input('enter a number...')
    try:  # checks if input is numeric, i.e. 2, 39, 4592 etc
        inp = int(inp) 
    except(ValueError):  # Was not numeric, i.e. was a letter, word or some 
# character
        try:
            inp = float(inp)  # Let's try again, could be user entered 3.5 or some other float value.
        except(ValueError):
            print("OK forget it")
```

This would cover the cases @schwobaseggl mentions in the comments of this question.

Also please do not take pictures of your code, but paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
random n = random.randint(1,21)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and  21: ")) 
try:
    while guess != n:
      print ("WRONG!")
      guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 24: ")) 
      if guess == n: 
        print ("RIGHT!")
except ValueError:
    if guess == "no":
      print ("OK forget it") 
   else: 
      print ("no idea what you want")
```

```

The problem here is the first `guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 24: "))` is before the `try` clause, and is therefore not covered by it and therefore when it errors it is not caught. Simply remove that line and it'll work fine!

P.S I have just realised that this way, every time you run the program it will say "WRONG!" before you start. The simplest fix is just to add a boolean `first` and if it's `true`, don't print "WRONG!", then set it to `false` after the first iteration. Alternatively (but uglier in my opinion), create a second try except clause for the first input